# How to make images size equal in table HTML

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML to make a table with images and I want these images to be the same size but I obtain this:

[image: images]

The images have the same resolution and my CSS is like this:

```
 img {   
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 50%;   
  height:50%;     
 }
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
        
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;color: #666633; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; ">name1</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;color: #666633; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; ">name2</td>
</tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="../assets/img/image1.jpg" alt="image"></td>

        <td><img src="../assets/img/image2.jpg" alt="image" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" [routerLink]= "['/detail',100]" style="margin-bottom:50px">View</button></td>

        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" [routerLink]= "['/detail',101]" style="margin-bottom:50px">View</button></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you paste your html code as well ? It'd help us to give answer

Comment: @John  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. It seems that one of the images was not the same resolution as the others. Using vw worked but the images were too close to each other. Finally I resized the image.

Comment: @John I am so happy to hear that my answer helped you a bit and can you do me a favour by accepting my answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but I would suggest you to use **vw** instead of **%** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive but it's your choice you can use **%** also. I am attaching source code and output, check your code with it and it will surely help. And sometimes it is the problem web browser, so most of the time use google chrome it does not have such problems.

```css
img{ 
  display: block; 
  margin: 2vw; 
  width: 10vw; 
  height: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Images in Table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="Images\sample1.jpg" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="Images\sample2.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: % makes also responsive. Please give an explanation how is better use vm or vh instead a %

Comment: @Sfili_81 I am not saying vw or vh is better than %. It depends on you, which you are more comfortable with and I like vw more than % because If you want to size your element based on the viewport width and not the parent/root element, you should use viewport units but Percent value is always relative to another value, be it the element’s parent value or from another property of the element itself. That is the reason I suggested vw and maybe the person will learn something new and would be more comfortable using viewport units. And yes % & vw both are responsive.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Hey, just wanted to know whether you liked my explanation or do I need to ameliorate my explanation?